# troposphere dynamodb syntax for code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, troposphere

I have following code I am trying to create a dynamodb table i have assigned resource code to a variable. I am unable to indent variable section in my file.

can some one help if the array for attribute and keyschema syntax is fine.what can i change to correct this indentation issue.

================

```
> dynamodb_table=Table(
>               "DYNAMODB_JWT_IAM",
>                       AttributeDefinitions = [AttributeDefinition([
>                               {
>                                 AttributeName="deviceId",
>                               AttributeType="HASH"
>                                      },
>                                  {
>                                                       AttributeName="solutionId",
>                                                       AttributeType="S"
>                                               }
>                                            )]],
>                       KeySchema = [KeySchema(
>               {
>                       AttributeName="solutionId",
>                                   KeyType="RANGE",
>                               },
>               {
>                                   AttributeName="deviceId",
>                               KeyType="HASH",
>                           }
>                           )],
>       ProvisionedThroughput = ProvisionedThroughput(
>               ReadCapacityUnits = 5L,
>                           WriteCapacityUnits = 6L,
>                           ),
>       TableName = DYNAMODB_JWT_IAM,
>                   Tags=dynamodb.Tags(dynamodb_tags)
>                   )   self.template.add_resource(dynamodb_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific about why you cannot correct the indentation programmatically?

I tidied up your indentation manually and discovered that your closing bracket sequence for `AttributeDefinition` is incorrect. See my comment below:

```python
dynamodb_table=Table(
    "DYNAMODB_JWT_IAM",
    AttributeDefinitions=[
        AttributeDefinition([
            {
                AttributeName="deviceId",
                AttributeType="HASH"
            },
            {
                AttributeName="solutionId",
                AttributeType="S"
            }
        )] # your closing bracket sequence is incorrect; switch the order of your closing parenthesis and square bracket
        ],
        KeySchema=[
            KeySchema(
                {
                    AttributeName="solutionId",
                    KeyType="RANGE",
                },
                {
                    AttributeName="deviceId",
                    KeyType="HASH",
                }
            )
        ],
        ProvisionedThroughput=ProvisionedThroughput(
            ReadCapacityUnits = 5L,
            WriteCapacityUnits = 6L,
        ),
        TableName=DYNAMODB_JWT_IAM,
        Tags=dynamodb.Tags(dynamodb_tags)
)
self.template.add_resource(dynamodb_table)
```

Comment: Thanks for identifying issue. i have resolved it earlier